# How to add a vector to each row in eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen

I am trying to add a vector to each row in a matrix, but I am getting error.

Here is the code:

```
MatrixXd shifted_cord = MatrixXd::Random(10,3);
Vector3d v = Vector3d(3.0,20.0,0.0);
//std::cout<<shifted_cord<<std::endl;
shifted_cord = shifted_cord.colwise()+v;  //(10,3)
```

I need to shift all rows, in this case 10.

Same thing is done in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811084/eigen-subtracting-vector-from-matrix-columns), but when I tried, I am getting error.

Error:

```
Assertion `aLhs.rows() == aRhs.rows() && aLhs.cols() == aRhs.cols()' failed.
```

Can anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add to each row, you need to write `.rowwise()` and make sure that the vector you add is indeed a row-vector (either declare `v` as `RowVector3d`, or write `v.transpose()`. Also you can use the `+=` operator with `.rowwise()` expressions:

```
shifted_cord = shifted_cord.rowwise()+v.transpose();
// or
shifted_cord.rowwise()+=v.transpose();
```