# Eigen MatrixXf subtract a VectorXf

Tags: matrix, eigen3

I have a `Eigen::MatrixXf mat` that has size of 113(rows) X 2009(cols); I am trying to subtract the max of each of its column from each of its column. Here is my code:

```
VectorXf minVal = mat.colwise().minCoeff();  // mat is MatrixXf
mat.colwise() -= minVal;
```

Here is the error message:

> Assertion failed: dst.rows() == src.rows() && dst.cols() ==
> src.cols(), file
> C:\cui\Projects\eigen-3.4.0\Eigen\src\Core\AssignEvaluator.h, line 754

Can anyone give a pointer? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811084/eigen-subtracting-vector-from-matrix-columns

Comment: No it does not. Because in the link the size of the matrix and vectors are clearly defined, whereas here in my problem the sizes are dynamic. They are MatrixXf instead of Matrix3D,

Comment: Pretty sure you just need to change the second line to ```rowwise()```. The logic is this: colwise reduction gives you one entry per column, preserving the number of rows. So you apply the subtraction to each row in the next step.

Comment: @Homer512
Compiling error C2338: YOU_PASSED_A_COLUMN_VECTOR_BUT_A_ROW_VECTOR_WAS_EXPECTED

Comment: ```mat.rowwise() -= minVal.transpose();``` Or change it to ```RowVectorXf minVal = ...```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mat.colwise().minCoeff()` returns a row vector (you can assign this to a column vector, because in most cases Eigen implicitly transposes row vectors to column vectors and vice versa).
You should store the result as a `Eigen::RowVectorXf` and then subtract that from each row, i.e., `mat.rowwise() -= minVal;`

This should work:

```
Eigen::RowVectorXf minVal = mat.colwise().minCoeff();

std::cout << mat << "\n\n" << minVal << "\n\n";

mat.rowwise() -= minVal;

std::cout << mat << "\n\n";
```

Comment: I must say that what Eigen calls a "row vector" is what my understanding as a column vector. Simply a row vector is horizontal, and a column is vector is vertical. Thanks you guys.